# Implement reading of contact from phone book Using Hashtable in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, contacts, lcdui, jsr75

I ran into a bind whereby I had to sort the data read from the phones PIM. In doing this I lost the other to which each contact field was referenced to the telephone number because I made use of 2 separate vectors as illustrated below
Before sorting

```
 Nna - +445535533                       
Ex - +373773737                         
Ab - +234575757                         
After sorting.(Which shouldn't be)
 Ab - +445535533
 Ex - +373773737
 Nna  - +234575757
```

This gives an undesired behavior since the sort removes the index to index pointer of the vectors and a selected name (in a Multiple list  Box) will get a wrong number.
Alternatively,
I used a hashtable, with the intention of using the names as keys and numbers as the values.
But this pairing means duplicate names being used as keys will not be allowed. Thus I made it a  i.e the phone number as keys instead.
I don't want to sound like a cry baby so I stop here for a while and so you the code with a hope u guys would understand it

**MY QUESTION**
1. Is there a better way/algorithm to implement this?
2. How do I implement the getSelectedItems() in such a ways that it grabs the numbers of the selected indexes of a MULTIPLE CHOICE LIST from a hashTable

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.pim.Contact;
import javax.microedition.pim.ContactList;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIM;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIMException;

/**
 *
 * @author nnanna
 */
public class LoadContacts implements Operation {

    private boolean available;
    private Vector telNames = new Vector();
    Vector telNumbers = new Vector();
    Hashtable Listcontact = new Hashtable();
    private String[] names;

    public Vector getTelNames() {
        return telNames;
    }

    public Hashtable getListcontact() {
        return Listcontact;
    }

    public void execute() {
        try {
// go through all the lists
            String[] allContactLists = PIM.getInstance().listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);

            if (allContactLists.length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < allContactLists.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(allContactLists[i]);
                    System.out.println(allContactLists.length);
                    loadNames(allContactLists[i]);
                    System.out.println("Execute()");
                }

            } else {
                available = false;
            }
        } catch (PIMException e) {
            available = false;

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            available = false;

        }
    }

    private void loadNames(String name) throws PIMException, SecurityException {
        ContactList contactList = null;

        try {
            contactList = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY, name);
            // First check that the fields we are interested in are supported(MODULARIZE)
            if (contactList.isSupportedField(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME) && contactList.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
                Enumeration items = contactList.items();
                Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
                while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
                    Contact contact = (Contact) items.nextElement();
                    int telCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
                    int nameCount = contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);
                    if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {
                        String contactName = contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
                        // go through all the phone availableContacts

                        for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Read Telno");
                            int telAttributes = contact.getAttributes(Contact.TEL, i);
                            String telNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);
                            Listcontact.put(telNumber, contactName);
                            temp.put(contactName, telNumber);
                        }
                        names = getSortedList();
//                            Listcontact = temp;
                        System.out.println(temp + "-------");
                        System.out.println(Listcontact + "*******");
                        shortenName(contactName, 20);
                    }
                    available = true;
                }
            } else {
                available = false;
            }
        } finally {
// always close it
            if (contactList != null) {
                contactList.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void shortenName(String name, int length) {
        if (name.length() > length) {
            name = name.substring(0, 17) + "...";
        }
    }

    public Vector getSelectedItems(List lbx) {
        boolean[] arrSel = new boolean[lbx.size()];
        Vector selectedNumbers = new Vector();
        int selected = lbx.getSelectedFlags(arrSel);
        String selectedString;
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSel.length; i++) {
            if (arrSel[i]) {
                selectedString = lbx.getString(lbx.getSelectedFlags(arrSel));
                result = result + " " + i;
                System.out.println(Listcontact.get(selectedString));
//                System.out.println(telNumbers.elementAt(i));
            }
        }
        return selectedNumbers;
    }

    private String[] sortResults(String data[]) {
        RecordSorter sorter = new RecordSorter();
        boolean changed = true;
        while (changed) {
            changed = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < (data.length - 1); j++) {
                String a = data[j], b = data[j + 1];
                if (a != null && b != null) {
                    int order = sorter.compare(a.getBytes(), b.getBytes());
                    if (order == RecordSorter.FOLLOWS) {
                        changed = true;
                        data[j] = b;
                        data[j + 1] = a;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public String[] getNames() {
        return names;
    }
        Vector elements = new Vector();
    private String[] getValueArray(Hashtable value) {

        System.out.println(Listcontact + " c");
        Enumeration e = value.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            elements.addElement(e.nextElement());
        }
        String[] elementsArray = new String[elements.size()];
        elements.copyInto(elementsArray);
        elements.removeAllElements();
        System.out.println(elementsArray + " k");
        return elementsArray;
    }

    public void getDuplicates(Vector realValue) {
        Vector duplicate = new Vector();
        Enumeration e = realValue.elements();
        for (int i = 0; e.hasMoreElements(); i++) {
            if (duplicate.isEmpty() || !duplicate.elementAt(i).equals(e.nextElement())) {
                break;
            } else {
                duplicate.addElement(e.nextElement());
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getSortedList() {
        return sortResults(getValueArray(Listcontact));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me reiterate you requirement: You want a method that will sort the contacts read from native phonebook, then alphabetically sort them on name.

Following is the approach,

Replace the vectors and hash-tables in your code with a single vector, say `contactListVector`, containing elements of type `ContactItem`, don't worry this class is explained below. Fundamentally the contact's *name* and *number(s)* are linked together in a `ContactItem`, hence you do not have to worry about there mappings which reduces the usage of redundant data structures.

```
class ContactItem {
    private String name;
    private String tnumber;  //this can also be a data structure 
                             //for storing multiple numbers

    ContactItem( String name, String tnumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tnumber = tnumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTnumber() {
        return tnumber;
    }

    public void setTnumber(String tnumber) {
        this.tnumber = tnumber;
    }        
}
```

You can reuse the sorting algorithm on `contactListVector` by comparing the member variable `ContactItem.name` of the vector element. Also you can deploy different sorts on member variables *numbers* and/or *names*. Also there are lots of libraries for JavaME available that have better sorting algorithm's implemented if need be use them.

I would recommend you to perform the sorting once on the `contactListVector` elements at the end of your method `loadNames(...)` maybe in the finally block triggered by some boolean variable. The current sorting call in each iteration on `items` enumeration is expensive and time consuming.

Also you can serialize / deserialize the `ContactItem` thus persist your contact list.

Let me know if you need detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am working on the implementation you gave,I'll let you know if I need more explanation

Answer (score 1):

What about inserting the contact name and numbers inside a recordStore , so you can later make a sort by creating a class which implements `RecordComparator`.

Answer (score 1):

This statement in your code makes no sense:

```
selectedString = lbx.getString(lbx.getSelectedFlags(arrSel))
```

Per [lcdui List API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#getSelectedFlags(boolean[])) above will return the string located at the index equal to *the number of selected elements* why would you need that?

---

If you need to output selected text for debugging purposes, use `lbx.getString(i)` instead.

To *implement the getSelectedItems() in such a ways that it grabs the numbers of the selected indexes of a MULTIPLE CHOICE LIST* do about as follows:

```
    public Vector getSelectedItems(List lbx) {
        boolean[] arrSel = new boolean[lbx.size()];
        Vector selectedNumbers = new Vector();
        int selected = lbx.getSelectedFlags(arrSel);
        System.out.println("selected: [" + selected + "] elements in list");
        String selectedString;
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSel.length; i++) {
            if (arrSel[i]) {
                // here, i is the selected index
                selectedNumbers.addElement(new Integer(i)); // add i to result
                String selectedString = lbx.getString(i);
                System.out.println("selected [" + selectedString
                        + "] text at index: [" + i + "]");
            }
        }
        return selectedNumbers;
    }
```

---

As for sorting needs, just drop the `HashTable` and use `Vector` of properly designed objects instead as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8402854/839601) - with your own sorting algorithm or one from some 3rd party J2ME library.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to have `Contact` class with name and Vector of numbers. And instead of sorting names array sort the array of contacts.

Comment: as opposed to Java SE, there's no `Comparator` in java ME [MIDP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html)

Comment: I completely forgot that we have own Comparator interface and sort utility method